# Como visualizar arquivos antes de executar o download?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, vue.js, download

Quero que um PDF(gerado no meu servidor) seja mandado para o meu cliente e aberto em uma nova aba antes de ser baixado. Já consegui fazer com que ele seja baixado diretamente quando vem do servidor para o cliente, porém, agora necessito que ele seja exibido ao invés de ser baixado.

Criei um servidor Express na versão 4.15.0 e o meu cliente foi feito em VueJS utilizando o Quasar Framework. Segue alguns códigos para ajudar no entendimento da pergunta:

Servidor:

```
pdfMake = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
let stream = pdfMake.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../pdfs/Tabela.pdf'));
pdfMake.end();

stream.on('finish', function() { //Método síncrono que só efetua o download do arquivo
                                 // depois que o PDF está criado
    if (fs.existsSync('C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf')) {
        let file = 'C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf';
        res.send(file); //Este método está certo?? Se não, qual devo usar??
    }
})
```

Cliente:

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/server/gerarpdf',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      data: this.pessoas
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      //Comentei o método abaixo pois ele efetuava o download, qual método devo utilizar para que o PDF seja visualizado ao invés de baixado??
      // link.download = 'TabelaTeste.pdf'
      link.click()
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça seu link abrir numa nova guia:

```
let link = document.createElement('a')    
link.target = '_blank'
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.href = url.replace(/([\w]{8})-([\w]{4}-){3}([\w]{12})/g, 'meuarquivo.pdf');
```

Comment: `let options = {
    root: '../pdfs/',
    dotfiles: 'deny'
   };
   let fileName = 'Tabela.pdf';
   res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err){
     console.log(err)
    }else{
     console.log(fileName + ' foi enviado!')
    }`

E o servidor estando assim está correto??

Comment: Pois ele está abrindo o arquivo, mas o nome está "
4098840a-9687-4fad-aa36-7e6f16f5a018"

Comment: Acredito que ele não vai obedecer o nome enviado pelo servidor, experimente descomentar a linha de código `link.download` @LeonardoEbert

Comment: Após descomentar a linha `link.download` o arquivo foi somente baixado, sem abrir em nova guia

Comment: De um `console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))` para ver o formato da URL. Poderemos renomear por ela @LeonardoEbert

Comment: Foi isso que apareceu no console: `blob:http://localhost:8080/960619d0-a0fa-4a6e-ba0e-6c0380669f1f`

Comment: Editado @LeonardoEbert

Comment: Testei e não funcionou, não acontece nada quando clico no botão...

Comment: Verifiquei a URL no navegador e ela fica assim: "blob:http://localhost:8080/2050102b-7041-4cfa-9ebf-0c05af158005"